# Add footer row to grid.mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, grid.mvc

I want to add a footer row were the user can add a new item like on this image.
[image: image of footer] I am using gid.MVC by Vyacheslav Bukharin. As you can see in this tutorial https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/creating-simple-grid-in-mvc-using-grid-mvc/

here is my code so far

```
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Add(c => c.cliente_id).Titled("Cliente ID");
                    columns.Add(c => c.nombre_cliente).Titled("Cliente name");
                    columns.Add()
                    .Filterable(false)
                    .Encoded(false)
                    .Sanitized(false)
                    .SetWidth(30)
                    .RenderValueAs(o => Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = o.cliente_id }));
                    columns.Add()
                    .Encoded(false)
                    .Sanitized(false)
                    .SetWidth(30)
                    .RenderValueAs(o => Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = o.cliente_id }));                        
                    }).WithPaging(10).Sortable(true).Filterable(true).WithMultipleFilters()
```

My question is how can i add the same footer as on the image in mvc. Thank you for your help

Comment: are you saying you want to add pagination to your grid?or something else

Comment: Yes my paging works and my sorting works however I would like to add a footer where the user can add a new objet.

Answer (score 0):

Include gridmvc.css to your layout.cshtml .filteriing and paging will start working.

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Gridmvc.css")" rel="stylesheet" 
type="text/css" />
```

Comment: My paging and filtering already works I would like to have a footer where I can write a new item. But thank you for your help.

Comment: @JuniorCortenbach.what do you mean by new item..i didn't get you

Comment: When I create a new item it opens a new page where I can add a item however I would prefer to be able to have text boxes under my grid like on my image with a (+) button so I can add a new item directly on the same page.